# MKV with FLAC to MP4 with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a MKV file with a H264 video track, FLAC audio track and ASS subtitle track. I want to convert the file to a MP4 but keep the video track and re-encode the audio and subtitle tracks. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-c`/`-codec` and `-map` options.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -c:v copy -c:a aac -c:s mov_text output.mp4
```

- `copy` enables [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode which only re-muxes and does not re-encode (the video in this example).
- See the [`ffmpeg` documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) for more info.